# Small circle inside simple polygon

Tags: computational-geometry

I've been working on a computational geometry problem and ran across the following problem (which is needed as a subroutine) but failed to find any good references or algorithms.

Given a simple (possibly concave) polygon P, the goal is to compute the center and radius of the smallest circle which is completely contained in P (empty circle) but touches the polygon in at least two places (point or edge). If the two "places" happen to be points of the polygon then there are no constraints. Also no constraints if we hit a point and an edge. But if we hit two edges then they should not be consecutive (assuming clockwise or counter-clockwise order).

I am aiming for an implementable algorithm running in order of n^3 or better. Any pointers, references, or ideas would be very helpful.

Thanks!
Amer

Comment: Interesting. I fiddled around with this for a while, but there are quite a lot of cases to consider. Even pragmatic approaches (like computing all "obvious candidates" and picking the "best" one) turn out to be difficult - and this still was before coming in touch with the nitty-gritty cases (e.g. parallel edges...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just looking for pointers or ideas, I'll be brief. The Medial Axis of a polygon is set of centers of the circles that touch the boundary in two or more locations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton#Centers_of_bi-tangent_circles).  Also known as a skeleton, the medial axis consists of a tree-like graph made of lines and parabolas.  If you check the circles at the vertices of this graph (ignoring the graph vertices that coincide with polygon vertices), you can find both the largest and smallest circles. You'll have to fine tune to accommodate your "no consecutive edges" requirement.

Comment: Hey brainjam, I did end up finding medial axis and medial axis transforms which seem like the best way to go until you start looking for nice implementations :) also it seems like I have to sacrifice accuracy for running time (if my understanding is correct the algorithms partition the 2D space into small squares, where small is a parameter). I was hoping for a somewhat simpler algorithm but I'm starting to doubt it. Thank you for your answer!